# How can I present a Game Center matchmaking view controller in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, game-center

I am working with SwiftUI and Game Center to create a multiplayer game. I am having trouble presenting a the GKMatchmakerViewController after initializing it with the amount of players and invite message. I have tried using a button to call my presentMatchmaker() function but this does not work. Any help is much appreciated!

```
func presentMatchmaker() {
        guard GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated else {
            return
        }
        let request = GKMatchRequest()
        request.minPlayers = 2
        request.maxPlayers = 7

        request.inviteMessage = "You have been challenged..."

        guard let vco = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request) else {
            return
        }
        self.ViewController?.present(vco, animated:true)
}
```